# xml version of APBRAIN package is not inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an xml layout which has the Ad agent - APBRAIN package. I do not understand why the layout is not inflating using the package - com.appbrain.AppBrainBanner. The other 2 buttons as shown in the xml is displayed properly. Kindly help me to resolve this.

### XML:

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center"   
    android:layout_weight="6" 
    android:weightSum="150" >  


    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >   
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bQuizHome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/nextslide"/> 
    </LinearLayout> 




    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >   
        <com.appbrain.AppBrainBanner 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout> 


    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/nextslide"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```